# getting sound using soundpool

Tags: android

I am a newbie to android development and am trying to develop a simple application where a button is used to play a sound. I am trying to use SoundPool and find that every tutorial gives such a code to be added after making a soundpool object:

```
soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
                    int status) {
                loaded = true;
            }
        });
```

but when i try to use this code in eclipse, it says

The method onLoadComplete(SoundPool, int, int) of type new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener(){} must override a superclass method.
and suggests to remove the @override notation. This should happen if there is no such method?? Why am i getting this error?

and when i put soundID = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.mysound, 1);

after the above code, eclipse says The method load(Context, int, int) in the type SoundPool is not applicable for the arguments (new View.OnClickListener(){}, int, int)

this is my entire code:
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

```
private SoundPool soundPool;
int soundID;
boolean loaded = false;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button bPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bPlay);
    final TextView aRing = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tAlarmRinging);

    bPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            aRing.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
                        int status) {
                    loaded = true;
                }
            });
            soundID = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.mysound, 1);
        }

        });
}
```

}

Comment: Does it compile when you build it??

Comment: it is giving me further errors also, even after i remove the ovverride notation

Comment: Does Your project have 8 API level in properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to set the project compliance level to java 1.7 or something like this.

Right click the project, goto Properties->Java Compiler->Check the Enable project specific settings->then select the highest compiler compliance level.

If this doesn't work, then right click the project, AndroidTools->Fix project properties.

Comment: but for the soundPool.load, it is still saying The method load(Context, int, int) in the type SoundPool is not applicable for the arguments (new View.OnClickListener(){}, int, int)

Comment: The problem is here,you are trying to pass a Object for Click Listener instead of a Context Object. You are making mistake in calling the method with wrong parameter

Comment: Change this   `soundPool.load(this, R.raw.mysound, 1);` to  soundPool.load(YourActivityName.this, R.raw.mysound, 1);